# Run "Bundle Install" w/o Installing a Specific Dependency Gem - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, bundler, hiredis

I'm trying to run `bundle` on a Win machine for an existing app. One of the gems is using `HiRedis` as a dependency. Since it is impossible to install HiRedis on Win:

- Is there a way to find out which gem is using HiRedis?
- Is there a way to run bundle command with `--without [hiredis]`?

Comment: You can find the gem which uses the hiredis, from the Gemfile.lock. Search for hiredis, and check to see under which Gem is that hiredis appearing.

Comment: @Coderhs you should add your answer to get marked and close this question

Comment: @Coderhs yep. Marked as "answered".  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the gem which uses the hiredis, from the Gemfile.lock. Search for hiredis, and check to see under which Gem is that hiredis appearing.